# How do I index an arbitrary set of labels for nodes to place?

Tags: tikz-pgf, variable

For example, I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,2,4,6}{
    \foreach \j in {0,2,4}{
        \draw (\i,\j) -- (\i,\j+1) -- (\i+1,\j+1) -- (\i+1,\j) -- (\i,\j);
    }
}
\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{1}
\foreach \y in {3.75,1.75,-0.25}
    \foreach \x in {0.5,2.3,4.5,6.5}
        \node at (\x,\y) {\arabic{mycount}\addtocounter{mycount}{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This will draw 12 rectangles, and label them 1 to 12, so I can do the node creation when the labels are from a counter.

My question is this-- what if I had a set of things I wanted to put inside each box, like {2,7,apple,pen}. How could I index those inside the \foreach structure to be able to label those without having to specify each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for the `count` key that one can use in `foreach` loops.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
 foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,7,apple,pen,cat,marmot,koala,squirrel,bear,duck,3,7}
 {({Mod(\Y-1,4)*2},{-int((\Y-1)/4)})
  node[draw,minimum width=1.8cm] {\X}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One could also say `count=\Y starting from 0` but typing `-1` twice is less efforts.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you so much! :D